# Insert into table, from view, Oracle, unable to extend temp segment

Tags: view, insert, extend, temp, segment

I have the following code in Oracle:

insert into table_x
    select * from view_y;
commit;

where view_y takes about half an hour to execute and returns about 400 000 records.

The problem is when I try to make the insert. The insert takes more than two hours and now it even can't get finished. 
The error is "Unable to extend temp segment by 64 in tablespace TEMP".

Please advice on another way to insert the data - from view into the table.

Thanks much!

Comment: You need to ask your DBA to give you more TEMP space. Or if acceptable, break down the insert into multiple segments to commit individually (partition the data by some field, but make sure it does not change while you do it).

Comment: Hi, @Thilo! Unfortunately the DBA refuses to extend the TEMP space. I was also thinking to partition the data but not by field, as the logic of the view is quite complex. I will try partitioning the data so that I commit it by chunks.   Not sure if this is the right direction in which I should make efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Before try of inserting you should first such big amount of records you should first make all indexes unusable.

Plain insert as select does not consume any TEMP space however it's used by keeping indexes updated. Having that in mind you would rather drop indexes on table_x next execute index statement and recreate them (or alternatively make them unusable and rebuilding them).